# C - Need to compare `n` lowest bits of an int for equality

Tags: c, bit, bit-manipulation

C - Need to compare `n` lowest bits of an int for equality.

I.e. n = 4;

xxxx1001 == xxxx1001 (x is don't care)

I.e. n = 2;
xxxxxx01 == xxxxxx01

Can't think of a nice way to do it without using masks, =).

Comment: There isn't any way to do it without using masks.

Comment: @Jonathan: Well, there actually is a way. You could use modulo 2 to get the lowest bits of the numbers to compare, then shift them one bit to compare the next bit. As you need a loop it's not very efficient, but it's possible.

Comment: You can also shift unwanted bits off the left, or multiply by a power of 2 so that the unwanted bits overflow.

Comment: @chrisharris: That requires that you know how many bits there are in an int, and that is not specified in the language. You may know it for a specific compiler on a specific system, but the code isn't portable.

Comment: What is wrong with using a mask?

Comment: @Guffa: the C language provides the sizeof keyword for this exact reason.

Answer (score 26):

Create the mask from the number of bits:

```
int mask = (1 << bits) - 1;
```

Then you use that to compare the values:

```
if ((a & mask) == (b & mask))
```

Comment: you could do a bit faster. see my answer.

Comment: @leiz: That might be faster, but todays CPUs are not that linear, so you won't know without actually profiling it. Either way it's just micro-optimizing, and I would go with what's more readable.

Comment: And as pointed out on leiz's answer, GCC transforms this into leiz's answer anyway. Stick with readable.

Answer (score 9):

If you really don't want to use masks (not that there is anything wrong with that!), then you could use a shift-left operator:

```
if( a << m == b << m )
{
}
```

where m is the total number of bits less the number you are interested in.  That is, in the example in the question, m is 4 (ie, 8 - 4).

Edit: to be clear - I have assumed the question indicated an 8 bit integer given the format used (eg, xxxx1001), but the solution is general in that it caters for any sized integer.  To determine the number of bits in the integer, use 8*sizeof(type), where type may be int, short, long, etc.

Comment: Isn't m=28? (if an int happen to be 32 bits).

Comment: A problem with this approach is that the number of bits in an int is not specified in the language. It may be predictable for a certain compiler on a certain system, but the code is not portable.

Comment: @Peter: the questions shows the integers in the format of "xxxx1001", so I assumed an 8 bit integer.  I defined m as "m is the total number of bits less the number you are interested in", so it would work for other sized integers too.

Comment: can be rewritten as if (((a^b)<<m) == 0)

Answer (score 4):

I think what need to do is xor the values and then use a mask.
For example,

```
(a ^ b) & (( 1<<n ) - 1)
```

Comment: An inversion is needed. "(a ^ b) & (( 1<<n ) - 1)" will be zero (false) if the lower n bits of a and b are the same.

Comment: Don't like this; it's far from clear what it does.  Code is better when you can look at it and immediately perceive its function.

Comment: GCC 4 will make that optimization for you anyway, when given Guffa's solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int i;
int theSame = 1;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if !(a >> i & 1) || !(b >> i & 1)
    {
        theSame = 0;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, definitely takes more time than Guffa's answer, but since the asker seems to have some difficulty understanding bitmasks, I thought it would be clearer because this breaks it down in to little chunks where you just worry about one bit at a time.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the modulo operator. For example n = 4 and you have to ints x and y:

```
if((x%16) == (y%16)){ ....
```

Hope this helps you.

Nick

Comment: You could use the modulo operator, but that would make people think you weren't really a C programmer. The bit masking solution is a much more idiomatic one in C. That fact that modulo is probably massively slower is a secondary concern.

Comment: And any compiler worth its salt translates modulo of a power of two to the appropriate mask. With the constraint that the number of bits desired is variable, this doesn't work so well, and the questioner needs to be directed to shift or mask explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with masks?

```
(a & 0x1111) == (b & 0x1111)
```

Comment: in your answer the number of bits can't change

Comment: @juanduke - nothing in the question explicitly states that this has to be a general solution for an arbitrary number of bits.

Comment: The hexadecimal constants you show are not the lowest order bits. That's every 4th bit set in the lowest 16.

Answer (score 0):

I will suppose the 4 low bits are equals
First use y=(a^b) to obtain this bit pattern (x means unknown)

```
xxxx0000
```

Then reverse the bit pattern with y=~y

```
xxxx1111
```

Then detect the first 0 with y^=(y+1)

```
xxx11111
```

Then shift n times to the right y>>=n

```
0000xxx1
```

If it's non nul then the lowest n bits were equal
So my solution would be

```
int are_lowest_n_bits_of_a_and_b_equals(int n,int a, int b)
/* return 0 if not equal, or non zero if equal */
{
   int y=~(a^b);
   return (y^(y+1))>>n;
}
```

It seems to work even for n=number_of_bits(int) thanks to sign bit propagation in signed arithmetic right shift, but if ever it's UB, we can simply test for (a==b) in such edge case.